# Error : Ensure that the 'dir.root' property '/mnt/data/alf_data' is pointing to the correct data location

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-enterprise

I am installing Alfresco 5.2 on 2 linux node's on with same schema.
On first node the alfresco is properly installed but on second linux node it is giving me error something like this(given below).I have changed reference of 'dir.root' every where it is used plus i have re-installed alfresco several times still no luck.

2017-05-05 08:30:55,307  ERROR [web.context.ContextLoader] [localhost-startStop-1] Context initialization failed
 org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 04050019 Ensure that the 'dir.root' property '/mnt/data/alf_data' is pointing to the correct data location.
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker.check(ConfigurationChecker.java:259)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker.access$0(ConfigurationChecker.java:198)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker$1$1.doWork(ConfigurationChecker.java:186)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:555)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker$1.execute(ConfigurationChecker.java:182)
        at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:464)
        at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:352)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker.onBootstrap(ConfigurationChecker.java:192)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:56)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:214)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:954)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:672)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1859)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
May 05, 2017 8:30:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener
org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 04050019 Ensure that the 'dir.root' property '/mnt/data/alf_data' is pointing to the correct data location.
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker.check(ConfigurationChecker.java:259)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker.access$0(ConfigurationChecker.java:198)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker$1$1.doWork(ConfigurationChecker.java:186)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:555)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker$1.execute(ConfigurationChecker.java:182)
        at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:464)
        at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:352)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker.onBootstrap(ConfigurationChecker.java:192)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:56)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:214)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:954)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:672)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1859)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco store data on 2 different places, as it is document management system it is having 2 things to store.First one is files and folder and second one is metadata related to that.Files are stored inside the alf_data folder and metadata information are getting stored in database.Two different alfresco instance can not pont to different database and save dir root location

Now if this things are not synced in alfresco in that case it will give above error.

If you are setting up clustering environment you should refer below link.AFAIK , its only supported in enterprise edition.

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/ha-intro.html

Comment: Hey Krutik Jayswal i followed the instructions in the docs now instead i am getting same error on both nodes.

Comment: @KalebereGaurav are you using Alfresco community? Because in that case it has no clustering OOTB option and the documentation you are using is for Enterprise only version.

Comment: I am using Enterprise version itself. I resolved this this problem of mine by copying alf_data from working vanilla instance of Alfresco 5.2 from working node to node which was giving above error and restarting it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a bit more information as to:
1. When you say

> I am installing Alfresco 5.2 on 2 linux node's on with same schema

Are you trying to setup two nodes in a cluster pointing to the same database? Also, is the 5.2 version enterprise or is it community edition?
If it is community edition, I don't think clustering is supported as per [Alfresco Versions comparison](https://www.alfresco.com/platform/content-services-ecm)

2. The location that you are using

> /mnt/data/alf_data

Is it a shared location across both the nodes? I am sure you must have verified this, but can you double check the permissions on the alf_data (it should be read/write enabled)

Answer (score -1):

Stop server.

Create new database in DB and then change `db.name=NEW_DATABASE_NAME` in alfresco-global.properties.

Start server.